# How to configure visual basic application to connect to remote sql database

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I just created my Visual basic application which connects and uses Sql database on my system.
And its working properly.

My Stupid problem is when i distribute my application to my friends on INTRANET/LAN, how do i make them communicate to my SQL Database on my system.

If this needs some study, kindly refer me the topics and references to learn.

Comment: What is your connection string? What type of database are you using? MySql, MSSQL, Access, SQLite? If your database engine is a server, is it accessible from the internet?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Connection String : "Data Source=UNKN0WN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PlaylistTEST;Integrated Security=True"
Database : Microsoft SQL Server 10.00.5500
Yes my database is a server, it is my pc, i installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and created a database.
I dont need INTERNET support, only INTRANET will do.

Comment: Notice that as i am also connected to intranet, my assigned ip is 10.0.2.88, So i created another database server with connection string "Data Source=10.0.2.88;Initial Catalog=NetworkTEST;Integrated Security=True" and this also works. But from my system only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you and your friend are in the same windows domain, you're going to have to turn off integrated security in the connection string:

```
"Server=10.0.2.88\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PlaylistTEST;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
```

and create the login for the database:

```
In MSSQL Server Management Studio, expand server ->  expand security -> 
right-click on logins -> new login -> 
  sql server authenication: enter user and password, then 
  user mapping -> check off database that they will access and select roles down below.
```

and most likely enable mixed logins under SQL Server:

```
In MSSQL Server Management Studio, Right-click on server -> Properties -> Security -> 
        Server Authentication -> SQL Server and Windows Authenication mode
```

and finally, possibly enable TCP/IP:

```
Programs -> MSSQL Server -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager -> 
         SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> 
         TCP/IP -> Right-click -> Enable
```

Comment: one ques, should i directly change connection string in app.config ?
WIll it cause connection problem?

Comment: If you distributed it to your friend's PC, then change it in the copy of the web config that resides on that server (no need to change it on yours).

Comment: I would like to ask something off topic. I found that people say its not secure to use password in connection string ! Is it true? IF, what are the alternatives of combining password in CODE ?
Thanks.

Comment: It's common to encrypt the password and store it in a web config or registry entry. At runtime, the password would be loaded, decrypted, and then substituted into place in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You typically would configure the connection string to the database in the app.config file.

Check out [connectionstring.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012) for different options you can include and/or configure.

You will also need to make sure that you create proper accounts for your friends, and that the computer the SQL database is running on will allow remote connections and to open up the firewall.

Comment: If he is using a file-based Sql database, this will not work.

Comment: @lynn No i am using Database server.

Answer (score 0):

Use connection string with the IP address of the database server:

```
Public connectionString As String = "Data Source=169.254.90.176,1433;Initial Catalog=Dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;"
```